# Loop through Chart objects in Excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I have seen plenty of code that loops through's in an individual worksheet, however I am trying to loop through charts that are individual sheets in the workbook.  My code is as follows (as you can see I am simply trying to save the charts as PDFs):

```
Sub ExportAllCharts()
Dim Current As Worksheet

' Loop through all of the worksheets in the active workbook.
For Each Current In Worksheets

   If TypeName(Current) = "Chart" Then
       objCht.ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
               "c:/" & Current.Name, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
               IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
   End If

Next
End Sub
```

Unfortunately, when the code loops through all the sheets in the workbook, for some reason it is skipping the charts. Is there an equivalent to `Worksheets` that applies to individual charts in Excel? Or is there perhaps another way of doing this that I haven't thought of?

Thanks!
David

Comment: Stand alone charts are not worksheets, they are chart sheets, or simply charts. That is why @tendim's answer works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tried a quick test with this code, and it printed the `Chart` worksheets:

```
Public Sub test()
    Dim oChart As Chart

    For Each oChart In ActiveWorkbook.Charts
        Debug.Print oChart.Name
    Next
End Sub
```

That should do what you need.  FYI a good place to start is with the VBA object browser, `View -> Object Browser` or F11 in the Excel Visual Basic Editor.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Not a problem; always glad to help!